# Black screen simulator at update to Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I have updated from Xcode 7 to Xcode 8. I had a project on Swift 2.2 and it works well but when I have updated to Xcode 8 and Swift 3 I only can see a black screen on the simulator.

I have tried using Clean and Clean Build Folder options but the black screen is still being shown. After that, Build option. Also, there is no errors on the console or in Xcode.

Did someone get the same error at updating to Swift 3.0? Or do you know something that I can check and could be the reason of my black screen? I cannot found any similar behaviour on Internet when updating to the new Swift version.

Comment: Try to debug the view hierarchy with the button in the debug area, you can understand a lot from there

Comment: I updated and it worked for me, maybe delete derived data

Comment: @Yitschak What do you mean about derived data? Images, libraries? And where can I debug the view hierarchy?

Comment: See the buttons in the debug area during runtime. One of them holds the run and let you see all the layers in the view hierarchy 3D. To remove derived data click "projects" and you will see a button to remove it, it will be built again when you compile the project

Comment: Sorry for the not giving screenshots and tell the exact buttons, I'm on the iOS app now

Comment: Make sure that you have an entry point - Initial View Controller set in Main.storyboard. If you have and it still shows black screen then see if the Initial View Controller has a file linked to it in Identity Inspector. If yes, and still no progress then clean you project with Shift + Cmd + K and then rebuild it. Hope this works.

Comment: @YashTamakuwala This does not work but you gave me the clue to get the solution :). Finally was that I had to remove the Initial View Controller mark to make it work. Now the project appears again on the simulator :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @YashTamakuwala because he gave me the clue that made me get the solution.

I have referenced the `Initial View Controller` as normal and it was linked correctly because it was also connected on `Identity Inspector`.

What I have to do is to remove the `Initial View Controller` mark and the navigation controller that was linked to the first View Controller. Then, I have set the `Initial View Controller` mark again to the `View Controller` and go to `Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller`.

After do that, the project is again being shown on the simulator, without black screens.

Comment: So now your IVC points to the Navigation Controller ? Glad I could be of help.

Comment: @YashTamakuwala Yes, and before it also pointed to the Navigation Controller. It is a bit strange because it seems that, despite it was linked before correctly (all apparently normal), Xcode8 broke the link. Removing it and set it again, it worked well.

Comment: Thats weird. This is something you can't even report as a bug since it won't be easily reproducible.

Comment: @YashTamakuwala Yes, I know that. It is a weird behaviour so I will wait to see if someone had some similar behaviour as me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used xib only but got the same problem.

Then I changed `application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool`

to `application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool`

and it worked :D

Note: You shouldn't copy and paste. Should let Xcode suggest :)